# Does Django Admin Site have Subform?

Tags: django, subform

Say there're two tables:

table: Company
field: ID, Company_Name

table: People
field: ID, People_Name, Company_ID

I used to use MS Access, create a people form, a company form, then bind people form into company form as a "Subform".

Now I am learning Django. Are there any ways to achieve the similar function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to edit both `Company` and `People` from the same screen, yes, these are called "Inline forms" in Django.

For using them in the admin site, see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

For the more general case (in your own views), see:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

eg (in `yourapp/admin.py`)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Company, People

class PeopleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = People

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PeopleInline,
    ]
```